# How do you make a reset button for a timer?

Tags: javascript, html, button, timer, restart

I need the timer to reset when you click a button. I need the reset button because the user can revisit a timer multiple times but the timer displays the timer time from when it was previously used + the timers current time.

Here is a snippet of one of the timers with it's designated button

Link to code: http://jsfiddle.net/bw2dfkyu/

```
 <script>


        
      function startTimer(duration, display) {
          var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
          setInterval(function () {
              minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
              seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);
    
              minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
              seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
    
              display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;
    
              if (--timer < 0) {
                  timer = 0;
              }
    
          }, 1000);
         
    
          }
      
    
           
    

      function start5Timer() {
          var fiveMinutes = 60 * 5,
              display5 = document.querySelector('#time5');
          startTimer(fiveMinutes, display5);
    
      }
      
  
  function show5Timer() {
          document.getElementById("button").style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById("timer5").style.display = "block";
        }

    </script>
    
    <button id="button" onclick= "show5Timer(); start5Timer();">Starts and Shows Timer</button>
    
    
      <div id=timer5 style ="display:none">
          <h1><span id="time5">5:00</span></h1>
          <p>click next when the timer ends *clicking nextBtn takes them to another div, I want this to also restart the time*</p>
          <button onclick="takeToNextDiv(); #();">
          next
          </button>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to save the interval return value, in order to use it later and delete the interval, and by doing so, resetting the timer and starting it over.
the setInterval returns an integer, on which you can call the clearInterval function.

```
var interval; 
function startTimer(duration, display) {
      var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
      if(interval)
          clearInterval(interval)
      interval = setInterval(function () {
          minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
          seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

          minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
          seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

          display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

          if (--timer < 0) {
              timer = 0;
          }

      }, 1000);
}
```